# Can i make this javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, text

Is there some way i can make this loop it just stays at the last "1"
http://pastebin.com/swDRrsfv

Also how do i properly space my code by 4 spaces?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're trying to concatenate..?

Try this... (just define repeats with however many times you want to add an additional one to your string).

```
afunc = function() {
  $html = "";
  for($1 = 0; $i < $repeats; $i++){
    $html .= '1';
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = $html;
    sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

You were just redefining innerHTML to 1 every time so it was going through all your commands, just not making a visible change since each value was the same.

**Code Formatting**

In answer to your question about 4-spacing coding, you can click the `{ }` tag to automatically change to code formatting, or just add 4-spaces minimum (plus any additional spacing) to the beginning of each line of code. You can look at the source of my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This code if you want the number to incrementally change (I counted 33 rows)

```
afunc = function() {
    for (i=0; i<33; i++)
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = i;
      sleep(1000);
    }
}
```